# error syntax in update statement

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

i am wondering what is wrong with my syntax in updating my user when i am updating it will always says error syntax in update statement

```
 With cmd
                    .Connection = con
                    .CommandText = ("UPDATE [User] SET Username='" & TextBox2.Text & "',FirstName='" & TextBox3.Text & "', LastName='" & TextBox4.Text & "',Password='" & TextBox5.Text & "' Where ID = '" & TextBox1.Text & "' ")
                    .ExecuteNonQuery()
                    .Dispose()
                    TextBox1.Text = ""
                    TextBox2.Text = ""
                    TextBox3.Text = ""
                    TextBox4.Text = ""
                    TextBox5.Text = ""

                    MsgBox("User Updated", vbInformation, "Information Message")
                    datagridShow1()
                    con.Close()
end with
```

I also tried this code

```
 With cmd
                    .Connection = con
                    .CommandText = ("UPDATE [User] SET Username='" & TextBox2.Text & "',FirstName='" & TextBox3.Text & "', LastName='" & TextBox4.Text & "',Password='" & TextBox5.Text & "' where [ID]=@UID ")
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("UID", CInt(TextBox1.Text))
                    .ExecuteNonQuery()
                    .Dispose()
                    TextBox1.Text = ""
                    TextBox2.Text = ""
                    TextBox3.Text = ""
                    TextBox4.Text = ""
                    TextBox5.Text = ""

                    MsgBox("User Updated", vbInformation, "Information Message")
                    datagridShow1()
                    con.Close()
 end with
```

Comment: try passing param with `@` like `.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UID"`

Comment: There's more than one issue.  Are you trying to use [tag:vb.net] within Microsoft Access (instead of [tag:VBA])?  You'll need to include more information in you question, as well as an MCVE.  (See this link to learn what that is: "[mcve]")

Comment: i tried that already but it has still the same problem

Comment: @ashleedawg im using vb.net (visual studio visual basic) and im using my database in ms access.

Comment: Why is .CommandText in parenthesis? Have you tried running this in Access? Maybe you will get a more specific error message. I see you know how to use parameters. Now you need to make all the rest into parameters. Make sure you add them in the same order that they appear in the query. This is an oddity of Access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Password` is a keyword in Access (JET/Ace) SQL. You need to enclose it in brackets. Also, ID is numerical, so shouldn't have single quotes.

```
.CommandText = ("UPDATE [User] SET Username='" & TextBox2.Text & "',FirstName='" & TextBox3.Text & "', LastName='" & TextBox4.Text & "',[Password]='" & TextBox5.Text & "' Where ID = " & TextBox1.Text & " ")
```

Note that your application is vulnerable to SQL injection, and storing passwords as plain text, as far as I can see. That's two of the most obvious, and easily fixed security problems.